# deploy my application on a JBoss server from Maven

Tags: java, maven, jboss, continuous-integration

I'm trying to accomplish deploy my application on a JBoss server from Maven, installed and configured the plugin, maven performs all its life cycle without displaying errors but the EAR does not go to Jboss. Will someone help me?

PS: with the RUN command he performs successfully deploy but the maven lock besides only work with the server off.

Plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <jbossHome>C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\Java\jboss-eap-6.3_producao</jbossHome>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <port>9998</port>
                <name>Stefanini</name>
                <password>Stefanini@10</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>undeploy</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filename>box.ear</filename>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>

                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filename>box.ear</filename>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Log console:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] box
[INFO] box - ejb
[INFO] box - web
[INFO] box - ear
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building box 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ box ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building box - ejb 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ejb\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Compiling 50 source files to C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ejb\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (default-ejb) @ box-ejb ---
[INFO] Building EJB box-ejb with EJB version 3.1
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ejb\target\box-ejb.jar
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building box - web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\web\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\web\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Compiling 33 source files to C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\web\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ box-web ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [box-web] in [C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\web\target\box-web]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\web\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [2139 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\web\target\box-web.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building box - ear 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:undeploy (undeploy) @ box-ear ---
Dez 19, 2014 9:01:45 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
Dez 19, 2014 9:01:45 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
Dez 19, 2014 9:01:45 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.12.GA
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:ear (default-ear) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Copying artifact [war:br.com:box-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] to [box-web.war]
[INFO] Copying artifact [ejb:br.com:box-ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] to [box-ejb.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13] to [lib/jackson-mapper-asl.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13] to [lib/jackson-core-asl.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:com.google.guava:guava:18.0] to [lib/guava.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:javax:javaee-api:7.0] to [lib/javaee-api.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.0] to [lib/javax.mail.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:javax.activation:activation:1.1] to [lib/activation.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:jboss:jbosssx:3.2.3] to [lib/jbosssx.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:jboss:jboss-common:3.2.3] to [lib/jboss-common.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:joda-time:joda-time:2.5] to [lib/joda-time.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7] to [lib/velocity.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1] to [lib/commons-collections.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4] to [lib/commons-lang.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-io:commons-io:2.4] to [lib/commons-io.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1] to [lib/commons-fileupload.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2] to [lib/maven-compiler-plugin.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-plugin-api.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-artifact.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.1] to [lib/plexus-utils.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-core:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-core.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-settings:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-settings.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:1.0-beta-2] to [lib/wagon-webdav.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:slide:slide-webdavlib:2.1] to [lib/slide-webdavlib.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:2.0.2] to [lib/commons-httpclient.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:jdom:jdom:1.0] to [lib/jdom.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:de.zeigermann.xml:xml-im-exporter:1.1] to [lib/xml-im-exporter.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4] to [lib/commons-logging.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-profile:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-profile.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-model.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-2] to [lib/wagon-provider-api.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-repository-metadata.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-error-diagnostics.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-project:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-project.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-plugin-registry.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-plugin-descriptor.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-artifact-manager.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:2.0.9] to [lib/maven-monitor.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:1.0] to [lib/maven-toolchain.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:0.1] to [lib/maven-shared-utils.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1] to [lib/jsr305.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:1.1] to [lib/maven-shared-incremental.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:1.5.5] to [lib/plexus-component-annotations.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:2.4] to [lib/plexus-compiler-api.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:2.4] to [lib/plexus-compiler-manager.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:2.4] to [lib/plexus-compiler-javac.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.5.5] to [lib/plexus-container-default.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:2.2.2] to [lib/plexus-classworlds.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:3.4] to [lib/xbean-reflect.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:log4j:log4j:1.2.12] to [lib/log4j.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:commons-logging:commons-logging-api:1.1] to [lib/commons-logging-api.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:com.google.collections:google-collections:1.0] to [lib/google-collections.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5] to [lib/mockito-all.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.primefaces:primefaces:5.1] to [lib/primefaces.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.primefaces.themes:all-themes:1.0.10] to [lib/all-themes.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.omnifaces:omnifaces:1.8.1] to [lib/omnifaces.jar]
[INFO] Could not find manifest file: C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\target\box\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF - Generating one
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\target\box.ear
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:deploy (deploy) @ box-ear >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:ear (default-ear) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] Could not find manifest file: C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\target\box\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF - Generating one
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\box-estudo\box\ear\target\box.ear
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:deploy (deploy) @ box-ear <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:deploy (deploy) @ box-ear ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] box ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.323 s]
[INFO] box - ejb ......................................... SUCCESS [  4.387 s]
[INFO] box - web ......................................... SUCCESS [  6.215 s]
[INFO] box - ear ......................................... SUCCESS [ 19.696 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30.829 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-19T09:02:03-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/470M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <configuration>
            <jbossHome>C:\Users\arcosta\Documents\Aurelio\Caixa\Java\jboss-eap-6.3_producao</jbossHome>
            <hostname>localhost</hostname>
            <port>9998</port>
            <name>Stefanini</name>
            <password>Stefanini@10</password>
        </configuration>
```

the tag  should be the compiled project, resolved:

```
<name>box.ear</name>
```